# How to set Httpwebrequest Authentication header with Authenticationresult

Tags: c#, http, authentication, web

I need to set the auth header for my http web request using the AuthenticationResult I get from AuthenticationContext:

```
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("http://blabla/token");

 Task<AuthenticationResult> resultTask = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
               "http://blabla/service",
               "SomeGuid",
               new Uri("http://authlogin"),
               new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, false));

 resultTask.Wait();
 AuthenticationResult result = resultTask.Result;
 HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://MyApi/method");
 //Set headers for request
```

I need to pass the authentication result to the header of my request. I know I can do

```
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = //something
```

I just don't know what that something should be. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is a Wiki article on basic HTTP Authentication which is passed in the header.

For convenience, here is some code that implements the basic Auth Token:

```
string auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password);
string enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(auth));
string cred = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", enc);
reqest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = cred;
```

Note that you can replace this by setting the request.Credential, instead of constructing your own header value. This makes the code cleaner, HOWEVER your request will not pass the Auth header UNLESS the server responds with an Auth failure (401), so this approach generates more network traffic on secured end points.

Comment: I've seen this. How would I convert the AuthenticationResult from my question to something like cred in this case?

Comment: My apologies, I missed that part of the question. I don't believe there is any way to obtain the password as that would open all sorts of security issues but info about the user can be extracted from the AuthenticationResult.UserInfo. What you do with it depends on what your needs are on the API. If you need to resolve it to an internal user, user mapping will be required.